# Unexpecting end of input?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out why my code is giving me this erro it feels like I have added enough "end" to have it passing but it is still giving me this error?

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  # GET and POST routes for login/signup
  # GET route renders(displays) login/signup page
  # POST is to create the session (receiving the login form, finding the user, loging in the user.)
  get '/login' do
    erb :login
  end

  # We want to be able to.. (find the user, verify user, log in the user, redirect user.)
  post '/login' do
    # Do not forget the key (email)
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    @user.authenticate(params[:password])
  end

  get '/signup'
    
  end

end
```

Comment: "I am trying to figure out why my code is giving me this erro", "it is still giving me this error" – It would help if you could tell us what "this error" is. Normally, the error will tell you *exactly* what is going wrong, it contains the name of the file where the error occurs, the line number, and the column number, and a message describing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `do` after `get '/signup'` and therefore Ruby thinks that there is no block passed to that method and complains about an *unexpected end*.